# php, ajax: two ajax responses (non-synchronized)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So, I have an ajax-POST from the client, that asks for some information.
I am thinking about letting a php file first perform a fast task that sends back just a number and after that perform a background task that takes a bit more time and sends back an array.

I wondered if it's possible to send the two responses separate - once they are ready.
If it is, how would I handle it on the frontend with javascript?

Comment: Your second task could set a session variable to indicate it's current state in php, while you could continuously poll the server from javascript to know when this session status has changed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Typical HTTP can only send responses in a Request->Response manner.

What you may be looking for is WebSockets, which keeps a connection open for further messaging from the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API